# Magento 2 cron job for custom module

Tags: magento2, cron

Setting up cron for a custom module what I believe I need to do is create a `\etc\crontab.xml` for the module.

What I also believe is happening is when the cron job `magento cron:run` runs  all jobs in the table `cron_schedule` are executed (as long as time <= scheduled_at).

If this is correct, how does my job `run_my_module` for my custom module (`my\module`) get in `cron_schedule`?  I've run `magento cron:run` manually but don't see my job in the table.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schedule is generated periodically during `magento cron:run` execution. Period is defined separately for each cron group in the admin panel (`Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Cron`). New job will be scheduled only when `Generate Schedules Every` minutes pass after previous generation.

Implementation can be found here `\Magento\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver::_generate`

Comment: Thanks @Alex!  My group id is "default" and I see  2 settings for "Cron configuration options for group: default"; 1) "Generate Schedules Every" and 2) "Schedule Ahead for".  Does "Generate Schedules Every" mean every time "magento cron:run" executes, it won't create a schedule for each job until after this "time"? Meaning if "Generate Schedules Every = 15", then a job won't be scheduled until 15 minutes has past?

Comment: Yes. Until 15 minutes have passed after the latest schedule generation.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

Create crontab.xml file in your custom module - app/code/Magenticians/Mymodule/etc and paste the following code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="default">
<job name="cron_name" instance="Magenticians\Mymodule\Cron\Run" method="execute">
<schedule>*/1 * * * *</schedule>-->
</job>
</group>
</config>
```

Now Create Run.php file in app/code/Magenticians/Mymodule/Cron and paste this code in it:

```
class Run 
{
   protected $_logger;
   public function __construct(
       \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
   ) 
    {
     $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

   public function execute()
   {
       //Edit it according to your requirement
       $this->_logger->debug('Cron run successfully');
       return $this;
   }
}
```

Go to Root directory using SSH and run the following commands:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cron:run
```

Go to var/log/debug.log and you will see the text Cron run successfully in it.

Comment: Can possible to schedule cron without 'php bin/magento cron:run'? I use default group for my custom cron.